# Provide config file to selenium-standalone NPM library

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, end-to-end, angular-test

So Selenium-standalone provides its [API to manage Selenium configs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone/v/6.17.0#application-programming-interface-api)

However, that file is in node module itself (node_modules/selenium-standalone/lib/default-config.js), so all my configs I set in there will be gone if node modules deleted.

And since it is added as a **devDependency**, I dont really care about production (if that makes any sense), but at least what I want is to provide my config file whenever I start the server - `selenium-standalone start` or add config file when `npm i` happens. Or what else I can do to keep that file when node modules reinstalled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a flag to specify custom config file:

`npx selenium-standalone install --config=/path/to/config.json`